# how to avoid multiple threads doing a merge on a single database row

Tags: multithreading, oracle, jms

We are building a trading system using (JMS, Weblogic and Oracle backend) where multiple trade events create journal entries which are merged into a single position row in the database table. That means multiple JMS consumers creating multiple journal entries all contending to get hold of a single position row to update it. Its not a scalable design because no matter how many consumers we have, they will get blocked too many times while waiting to get lock on a single oracle row. (Because we have a few distinct positions on which most of the activity is happening).

As an alternative, we can just keep inserting journal entries. Every insert into journal entry can be further published as an event into a queue and the consumer can call an oracle view (which runs an aggregate query) to publish things downstream.

This 2nd solution has other issues like the time it will take to compute the oracle view as the number of journal entries will keep growing over time.

Is there any other way that this can be designed ?

Comment: I don't have an answer, just a few ideas that might be worth exploring. Have you looked at Oracle AQ - I believe it may even have a JMS interface or some sort. The other approach might be to uses a in memory database in front of the back-end (e.g. Times 10) to service the components and then stamp the final position to the database. On one project we weren't happy with the performance so the team wrote their own in-memory cache.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. without looking at the products that you mentioned, can i summarize your suggestion to this - "try using in-memory products to do the merge operation than doing them in oracle database, that might make it faster" 

please confirm.

Comment: AQ is not an in memory database - it's robust, prov en, scaleable messing/queuing system built by/for/within Oracle, and it has been around since 8i. Effectively using AQ you'll be able to queue your updates - might not be exactly what you want, but worth a look at. For fast performance trading type systems I have worked on the in-memory database approach seems popular.